# Broken HDMI Sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

```
12:35:09 pulseaudio: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_09.2" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_09.2" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.

12:35:09 pulseaudio: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_09.2" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_09.2" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
12:35:09 pulseaudio: Failed to find a working profile.

12:35:06 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)

12:35:05 kernel: kfd kfd: amdgpu: STONEY  not supported in kfd
12:35:00 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:09.2: no codecs found!
12:35:00 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:09.2: no codecs found!
12:35:00 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:01.1: no codecs initialized
12:35:00 kernel: hdaudio hdaudioC0D0: no AFG or MFG node found
```

So it looks like the update to 22.04.2 took out my GPU and high-def audio HDMI.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: This happened to me too. Pretty sure it's the same update. Anyone have a fix?